# How to get the list of the paired devices through Bluetooth in iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, external-accessory

It's for AppStore, so I don't want any private framework.

I want to get the list of the paired(even not connected).

There are Core Bluetooth and External Accessary frameworks in iOS.
I tried both of these, but nothing listed.

Answer (score -1):

Tyr to use this one but i'm not sure its working or not for offline devices.

Create EAAccessory object and initialize it. And then call the property name on your accessory object

```
NSArray *accessories = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] 
                        connectedAccessories]; 
EAAccessory *accessory = nil; 

for (EAAccessory *obj in accessories)
{ 
    NSLog(@"Found accessory named: %@", obj.name);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for Offline devices. It show only the one connected in "classical" Bluetooth. I'm not sure you can't get the ones which aren't currently connected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments. So, is it impossible to get all the devices in the Bluetooth section of Settings?

Comment: i don't know dear. I explained my self as i know.

Comment: @JinX. Did you find anything?